# How to get different maximum matchings

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, graph-theory, bipartite

I have a large bipartite graph and I can find a maximum matching quickly using [Hopcroft-Karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm). But what I would really like is a few hundred different maximum matchings for the same graph. How can I get those?

Here is an example small bipartite graph with a maximum matching shown.

[image]

Similar graphs can be made with:

```
import igraph as ig
from scipy.sparse import random, find
from scipy import stats
from numpy.random import default_rng
import numpy as np
from igraph import Graph, plot
np.random.seed(7)
rng = default_rng()
rvs = stats.poisson(2).rvs
S = random(20, 20, density=0.35, random_state=rng, data_rvs=rvs)
triples = [*zip(*find(S))]
edges = [(triple[0], triple[1]+20) for triple in triples]
print(edges)
types = [0]*20+[1]*20
g = Graph.Bipartite(types, edges)
matching = g.maximum_bipartite_matching()
layout = g.layout_bipartite()
visual_style={}
visual_style["vertex_size"] = 10
visual_style["bbox"] = (600,300)
plot(g, bbox=(600, 200), layout=g.layout_bipartite(), vertex_size=20, vertex_label=range(g.vcount()), 
    vertex_color="lightblue", edge_width=[5 if e.target == matching.match_of(e.source) else 1.0 for e in g.es], edge_color=["red" if e.target == matching.match_of(e.source) else "black" for e in g.es]
    )
```

Comment: You give example code using Python but did not tag this with Python. Are you looking for an answer specifically in Python or not? If Python only then please add the tag [tag:python] , if not then please add the tag [tag:lalanguage-agnostic]. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There’s an enumeration algorithm due to Fukuda and Matsui (“Finding all the perfect matchings in bipartite graphs”), ([pdf](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.53.469&rep=rep1&type=pdf)) which was improved for non-sparse graphs by Uno (“Algorithms for enumerating all perfect,
maximum and maximal matchings in bipartite graphs”) at the cost of more implementation complexity.

Given the graph G, we find a matching M (e.g., with Hopcroft–Karp) to
pass along with G to the root of a recursive enumeration procedure. On
input (G, M), if M is empty, then the procedure yields M. Otherwise, the
procedure chooses an arbitrary e ∈ M. A maximum matching in G either
contains e or not. To enumerate the matchings that contain e, delete e’s
endpoints from G to obtain G′, delete e from M to obtain M′, make a
recursive call for (G′, M′), and add e to all of the matchings returned.
To enumerate the matchings that don’t contain e, delete e from G to
obtain G′′ and look for an augmenting path with respect to (G′′, M′). If
we find a new maximum matching M′′ thereby, recur on (G′′, M′′).

With Python you can implement this procedure using generators and then
grab as many matchings as you like.

```py
def augment_bipartite_matching(g, m, u_cover=None, v_cover=None):
    level = set(g)
    level.difference_update(m.values())
    u_parent = {u: None for u in level}
    v_parent = {}
    while level:
        next_level = set()
        for u in level:
            for v in g[u]:
                if v in v_parent:
                    continue
                v_parent[v] = u
                if v not in m:
                    while v is not None:
                        u = v_parent[v]
                        m[v] = u
                        v = u_parent[u]
                    return True
                if m[v] not in u_parent:
                    u_parent[m[v]] = v
                    next_level.add(m[v])
        level = next_level
    if u_cover is not None:
        u_cover.update(g)
        u_cover.difference_update(u_parent)
    if v_cover is not None:
        v_cover.update(v_parent)
    return False


def max_bipartite_matching_and_min_vertex_cover(g):
    m = {}
    u_cover = set()
    v_cover = set()
    while augment_bipartite_matching(g, m, u_cover, v_cover):
        pass
    return m, u_cover, v_cover


def max_bipartite_matchings(g, m):
    if not m:
        yield {}
        return
    m_prime = m.copy()
    v, u = m_prime.popitem()
    g_prime = {w: g[w] - {v} for w in g if w != u}
    for m in max_bipartite_matchings(g_prime, m_prime):
        assert v not in m
        m[v] = u
        yield m
    g_prime_prime = {w: g[w] - {v} if w == u else g[w] for w in g}
    if augment_bipartite_matching(g_prime_prime, m_prime):
        yield from max_bipartite_matchings(g_prime_prime, m_prime)


# Test code

import itertools
import random


def erdos_renyi_random_bipartite_graph(n_u, n_v, p):
    return {u: {v for v in range(n_v) if random.random() < p} for u in range(n_u)}


def is_bipartite_matching(g, m):
    for v, u in m.items():
        if u not in g or v not in g[u]:
            return False
    return len(set(m.values())) == len(m)


def is_bipartite_vertex_cover(g, u_cover, v_cover):
    for u in g:
        if u in u_cover:
            continue
        for v in g[u]:
            if v not in v_cover:
                return False
    return True


def is_max_bipartite_matching(g, m, u_cover, v_cover):
    return (
        is_bipartite_matching(g, m)
        and is_bipartite_vertex_cover(g, u_cover, v_cover)
        and len(m) == len(u_cover) + len(v_cover)
    )


def brute_force_count_bipartite_matchings(g, k):
    g_edges = [(v, u) for u in g for v in g[u]]
    count = 0
    for m_edges in itertools.combinations(g_edges, k):
        m = dict(m_edges)
        if len(m) == k and is_bipartite_matching(g, m):
            count += 1
    return count


def test():
    g = erdos_renyi_random_bipartite_graph(7, 7, 0.35)
    m, u_cover, v_cover = max_bipartite_matching_and_min_vertex_cover(g)
    assert is_max_bipartite_matching(g, m, u_cover, v_cover)

    count = 0
    for m_prime in max_bipartite_matchings(g, m):
        assert is_bipartite_matching(g, m_prime)
        assert len(m_prime) == len(m)
        count += 1
    assert brute_force_count_bipartite_matchings(g, len(m)) == count


for i in range(100):
    test()
```